# Control power through a resistive load from a DC source and achieve low current peaks

Tags: power, dc, high-voltage, switching, resistive-load

I want to control the power through a resistive load from a DC source and achieve low current peaks. The use case is 0-1000VDC and 0-15kW (not for the entire voltage range). All other parameters and circuit design are changeable.

Right now I am using a transistor to switch (PWM) a mostly resistive load to control the power through it. Essentially the circuit looks like this (there are more diodes, filters etc) and uses a very low switching frequency (100Hz approximately, this can be changed if it helps the design).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flMfbY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since this circuit is intended to be used for a very large voltage input range and with a large power span certain operation points leads to a very large current peak compared to the average current through the resistor. This means that the DC source needs to be able to supply very large currents despite having a relatively low average current output. That phenomenon severly limits the usefulness of the DC source for powering other applications at the same time since we might end up blowing a fuse despite drawing relatively low average current. The simplest idea I have had to solve this is to have a large capacitor that smoothes out the current draw and increase the switching frequency.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqnF0S.png)</sup>

This of course introduces a plethora of other issues: possible EMC issues due to switching faster, and the fact that we have large capacitor that is not being discharged if the load is turned off for longer periods of time. These problems could of course be helped by using discharge resistors and the EMC can be helped by other design choices.

Another idea is to divide the load between more resistive loads with higher individual resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHnA74.png)</sup>

Then only using some of them and only switching one at a time while the others are either turned of or fully conducting depeneding on the use case. This a problem since we will have a way bigger system etc.

But before I go down any of these tracks I would like to check if there are any other ideas of how to solve this issue. I want power control of a resistive load from a DC source with low current peaks compared to average current.

All input is appreciated!

Comment: Use an inductor to turn it into a buck converter. However, your very wide range requirement needs a better specification to come up with a practical solution. What's the mean and maximum current at various voltages points.

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes that is a good idea! I thought about making the driving circuit for the resistance load into a DC-DC but initially avoided this to simplify the design, but maybe this will be the best solution anyway. The specifications are not really set since this an expirement/concept generation. I can make some guesses about how a practical solution would have to perform. 15kW when Vin > 500V, so if we decide the resistor from R1 = 16.6667, I_avg_max = 30A. The other criteria is essentially just keep the peaks as close to the average current as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For high power, a big slow FET (X5) with low RdsON switches the resistor directly using slow PWM, without inductor losses.

For low power, a small fast FET (X4) turns it into a buck converter. You'll need frequency above 10kHz to avoid a huge inductor though.

The load is tied to Vin so it shouldn't be too hard to add an EMI filter.

If you have other loads in the system, at low power you could switch the resistor in series with the source instead of drawing power from the supply

Comment: Oh this looks interesting! Why can I not just always use it as a buck converter and just use a FET with low RdsOn as X4? Is it due to EMC issues since we need such a high frequency? If I am not space constrained could I use a really large inductor to drop the switching frequency, not all the way down to 100Hz but lower than 10kHz, or will this cause other issues?

Comment: It depends. Your inductor will have resistance and other losses, so at high current if you want 100% duty cycle, it could be interesting to use a second FET for a direct path. Also a bigger lower RdsON FET will switch slower and have more switching losses than a smaller FET, but the latter will have more conduction losses. Basically, you should do the calculation and check if it's worth it.

Comment: Yes! But I forgot to mention that heating losses could be used since the resistive load is a resistance wire used for heating so the losses in the inductor when conducting could perhaps be used for heating as well with a clever mechanical design. The choice of FET and switching speed I need to do some hard thinking about. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: What is the resistor heating? Air?

Comment: Either air, water, coolant or oil. This is a concept study for a control circuit for electrical heating.

Comment: OK, if it's a resistor for air, it's just a wire around a former so it shouldn't be too difficult to have several taps for different power. But that's not the case for a water heating resistor. Is the power source a solar panel?

Comment: The heating element will change for the different application for liquids it will be tubular heating element and in air an aluminium stamped profile with the wire inside it. The application we are looking at right now would be a lithium ion battery bank but directly to a solar panel could be quite interesting as well!

Comment: So you want a wide range of allowed input voltage to handle various types of batteries?

Comment: Yes and varying state of charge!